# Paypal IPN callback stopped working in sandbox environment

Tags: paypal, callback, sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm having a problem with the paypal IPN callback. Paypal's IPN callback stopped working, in sandbox environment.

I've been testing my client's website, for the past weeks, and it has always been working correctly - The payment was made, and a callback IPN was sent back to the website, confirming the payment, and updating the website's database.

I haven´t change anything in my code, and it suddenly stopped working. The payment is still made and saved in the paypal account, but the IPN is always retrying... it doesn't complete.

Here's the code in use:

```
<?php

// STEP 1: read POST data

// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
$keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
if (count($keyval) == 2)
$myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
$get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) { 
if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
} else {
$value = urlencode($value);
}
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from [link removed] and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
// error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
curl_close($ch);
exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

……

?>
```

Firing some outputs to text files, I discovered that it passes the first Step and stops on the Second, before

```
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
```

I've already submitted three help requests to PayPal, but still didn't get an answer from them.

Comment: see this documentation it may help https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

Comment: Hello Danish, 

Thank you for your response.

I´ve allready tested that script. It was the firt one i´ve tried. Then i changed to the following script: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/

This script was working perfectly, but suddenly it stopped working.

Thanx

Comment: I´ve been testing and it seems the problem is related to Curl.
The IPN is supposed to work this way:
1 - paypal sends the callback with the transaction vars
2 - from the receiving file those vars are sent again to paypal, for confirmation
3 - paypal validates the received information
4 - paypal respondes "VERIFIED" or "INVALID"
In my callback file, the received vars are parsed and sent back to paypal correctly.

If I copy the url and submit it directly in the browser, i get the "VERIFIED" response.
But when submitted via Curl, it gives an error (couldn't connect to host).

Any Ideas?

Thanx

Comment: After lunch, magically it started working again in sandbox... But when i passed it to Live it stopped working again. The IPN doesn´t reach my callback file (I presume) and gives a HTTP error (406). Any Clues? Do I need to configure anything besides the link in the Curl? Thanx

Answer (score 2):

The cURL request initiates a HTTP POST back to PayPal in order to validate the IPN message. If it stops at this step, it means you *do* receive the IPN POST from PayPal, but you've got a problem connecting back to PayPal.

What does `// error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");` contain?

In order to resolve this, test the HTTPS connection from your server to the following addresses:

- https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate
- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate

For example, you can run cURL directly from your server (assuming you've got SSH access);

`curl -v https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate`

This should return something similar to the following:

```
$ curl -v https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate
* About to connect() to www.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.0.82.77...
* connected
* Connected to www.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.77) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware; businessCategory=Private Organization; serialNumber=3014267; C=US; postalCode=95131-2021; ST=California; L=San Jose; street=2211 N 1st St; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=www.sandbox.paypal.com
*        start date: 2011-09-01 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2013-09-30 23:59:59 GMT
*        common name: www.sandbox.paypal.com (matched)
*        issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.1
> Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2013 20:15:53 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Set-Cookie: xxxxx    
< X-Cnection: close
< Set-Cookie: xxxx domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.128.11.1376511353229960; path=/; expires=Fri, 07-Aug-43 20:15:53 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
* Connection #0 to host www.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
**INVALID* Closing connection #0**
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

If you receive a timeout or an SSL handshake error, you will need to investigate this separately.

Comment: Hello Robert,
Thanx for the answer. It's working again. The payments I´ve made yesterday (LIVE) where pending, but today they where already confirmed. I tested 2 more, and they where confirmed (IPN) automatically.
Is there any explanation for these strange things:
- 26 Jul - IPN stops working - sandbox.
- 14 Aug - IPN works again - sandbox.
- 14 Aug - IPN stops working - Live Mode (406 error).
- 15 Aug - IPN works again - Live Mode.
Without any change from my part.
Here are all the tickets submitted to paypal:#130810-000033,#130804-000067,#130731-000377,#130726-000079.
Thanx

Comment: From my side, no, nothing that I can see would explain that. You might have possibly been unable to connect to the IPN validation endpoint for a number of days, but why that would be the case I can't be sure (we do not blacklist IP addresses).

Comment: Thanx Robert. I guess I'll never know, but what matters is that is working ok now :) thank for the help again.